# CSS issue in JQuery date picker

Tags: jquery, css

I am using below script for date picker in JQuery:

```
         $('#dob').datepicker({
            minDate: new Date(1900,1-1,1), maxDate: '-18Y',
            dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '-100:-18'
        });
```

But Date picker goes under the table and only header portion is showing rest portion are hide into the table.

I have tried with below css which I putted in style.css but not solved.

```
.ui-datepicker{ z-index: 9999 !important;}
```

How to solve this issue? Please help

Answer (score 2):

Use `z-index` while calling the function like this

```
$('#dob').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(1900,1-1,1), maxDate: '-18Y',
    dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '-100:-18',
    //comment the beforeShow handler if you want to see the ugly overlay
    beforeShow: function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.ui-datepicker-div').css({'position': 'relative', 'z-index': 99999999999999});
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: I also need to add the parameter which I used in my posted example . How Can use those parameter with your method?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but IE<9 (or 10?) doesn't know about values lower than 10ms on `setTimeout`.

Comment: Due to this position absolute date picker goes below of the page

Comment: sry about the miss css should apply on `.ui-datepicker-div`. Try and tell me its working??

Comment: Still not working. Still its showing only header of datepicker in all browser.

Comment: Could you share your code i need to rectify myself.

Comment: actually its taking time to come full date picker. Max to max 10 -15 sec taking time for showing complete view